# Dynamic image display for android in corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

```
imageSuffix =
            {
                ["-x2"] = 2,
                ["-x4"] = 4,--ipad3
            }
```

i creaded app in corona for iphone in that app i worte  some like that for dynamic image Resulation and like that i want to know what procedure for android build the same project and i want know one more thing that is we mention any premission in build.settings file any thing for android did u explain to me

Comment: I really do not understood your question

Answer (score 0):

its the Images dynamic scale factor for android to set config.lua .its code for

```
imageSuffix =
        {
            ["-x15"] = 1.5,--android devices
            ["-x3"] = 3,--mid size tablet
        }
```